# How do I write a Apollo Server plugin to log the request and its duration

Tags: typescript, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I am surprised I could not find a library or example to do the following:

I want a simple server log of each request to the server that will state what query or mutation was requested, and the elapsed time it took to complete the request

I know there is the [plugin and extension](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/) frameworks.  But I am not sure what the best practice is to keep state between the two callbacks: `requestDidStart` and `willSendResponse`

something that would spit out:

```
path="createAccountMutation" service=20ms
```

extra credit would be to show the size of the payload

```
path="createAccountMutation" service=20ms bytes=355
```

Would love to see the solution in typescript

Note: I found [apollo-log](https://github.com/shellscape/apollo-log) -- but it does not do request duration

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`requestDidStart` is called once per request and returns a map of request lifecycle hooks, so you can initialize any state persisted between the hooks there.

```
const LogPlugin = {
  requestDidStart(requestContext) {
    const start = Date.now()
    let op

    return {
      didResolveOperation (context) {
        op = context.operationName
      },
      willSendResponse (context) {
        const stop = Date.now()
        const elapsed = stop - start
        const size = JSON.stringify(context.response).length * 2
        console.log(
          `Operation ${op} completed in ${elapsed} ms and returned ${size} bytes`
        )
      }
    }
  },
}
```

Note that this will only work on a per-request basis. If you need something more granular, like tracking how long an individual field takes to resolve, you'd need to utilize a [directive](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/graphql-tools/schema-directives) or [middleware](https://github.com/prisma-labs/graphql-middleware)

Comment: dude -- this looks amazing.  (bonus fist bump if you make it typescript ;-) ) [but really i bet I could figure that out]!  Thanks . (i'll give it a check once I prove that it works)

Comment: Is it possible to only catch any "mutations" at the willSendResponse?

Comment: don't forget to make "async requestDidStart" , "async didResolveOperation" and "async willSendResponse" for apollo v3

Comment: Pretty good answer! Only one point to add: you can use `requestContext.operationName` instead of creating a temporary variable and get the name from `didResolveOperation`.

Answer (score 6):

Here it is in Typescript

```
import {
  ApolloServerPlugin,
} from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';

import { GraphQLRequestContext } from 'apollo-server-types';
import { GraphQLRequestListener } from 'apollo-server-plugin-base/src/index'



// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59988906/how-do-i-write-a-apollo-server-plugin-to-log-the-request-and-its-duration
export const LogPlugin: ApolloServerPlugin  = {
  requestDidStart<TContext>(_: GraphQLRequestContext<TContext>): GraphQLRequestListener<TContext> {
    const start = Date.now()
    let op: string

    return {
      didResolveOperation (context) {
        op = context.operationName
      },
      willSendResponse (context) {
        const stop = Date.now()
        const elapsed = stop - start
        const size = JSON.stringify(context.response).length * 2
        console.log(
          `operataion=${op} duration=${elapsed}ms bytes=${size}`
        )
      }
    }
  },
}
```

all credit goes to Daniel Rearden

Answer (score 3):

I expanded on Daniel Rearden's and Jonathan's answers to make it work for me. The `ApolloServerPlugin` type require async calls. Maybe that's because I'm using ApolloClient v.3? Also, the operation variable must be typed to `null` since it's initialized as null.

Anyways, here's a working example of what I did. I also took the liberty of renaming the plugin, operation variable, adding an error logger and using `performance.now()` instead of `Date.now()`.

Also note that `MyApolloContext` is your own defined context (at least when using `apollo-server-express`)

```js
import { MyModels } from './models'
import {
  ApolloServerPlugin,
} from 'apollo-server-plugin-base';

import { GraphQLRequestContext } from 'apollo-server-types';
import { GraphQLRequestListener } from 'apollo-server-plugin-base/src/index'
import { performance } from 'perf_hooks'


export interface MyApolloContext {
  models: MyModels 
}

export const myDebugLoggerPlugin: ApolloServerPlugin = {
  async requestDidStart<MyApolloContext >(
    requestContext: GraphQLRequestContext<MyApolloContext >,
  ): Promise<GraphQLRequestListener<MyApolloContext >> {
    const start = performance.now()
    let operation: string | null

    return {
      // Apollo server lifetime methods that you can use. https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/integrations/plugins/#responding-to-request-lifecycle-events
      async didResolveOperation(context) {
        operation = context.operationName
      },
      async willSendResponse(context) {
        const elapsed = Math.round(performance.now() - start)
        const size = JSON.stringify(context.response).length * 2
        console.log(
          `ApolloServer log: operataion=${operation} duration=${elapsed}ms bytes=${size}`,
        )
      },
      async didEncounterErrors(context) {
        console.log('Did encounter error: ', context)
      },
    }
  },
  async serverWillStart(_context) {},
}
```